# Indexpath is nill after searching for an item

Tags: swift

So here is my code. I created a table with search bar, and i expected that after searching and clicking on that, it will show me the details on another view Controller. My thought is because indexpath is nill after rearranging table row. But I do not know how to fix it. PLease help me out

```
import UIKit

class STableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var searchController: UISearchController!
    var resultSearchController = UITableViewController()
    var filterList = Array<String>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.resultSearchController.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultSearchController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filterList = getList.filter({ (list: String) -> Bool in
            if list.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
            {

                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        })
        self.resultSearchController.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if tableView == self.tableView {
        return getList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return filterList.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell1 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
        if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell1.textLabel?.text = getList[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {cell1.textLabel?.text = filterList[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell1

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if self.tableView != nil {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchShow", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "SearchShow")
        {
            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController
            {
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                let titleString = getDesc[indexPath!.row]

                destination.getDesc = titleString
                self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == .Delete
        {
            getDesc.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            getList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(getList, forKey: "Name")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(getDesc, forKey: "Desc")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Are you using `UISearchController`? Please post the code where you set up the search (not as an image, but as text _formatted as code_ in your question).

Comment: 1) You mean `nil`, not `nill`. 2) Don't ever ever post a screenshot of your code; it forces people trying to help you to have to type in all over again. Paste the code as text into your answer.

Comment: 3) What's with the "[...]" enclosing your answer?

Comment: Sorry guys, I will post it now

Comment: It was break at prepareForSegue function